# Error with devise: "You are already signed in" without users in the database (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for my clients authentication, however, when I hit the sign up button in my view it throws me that I am already signed in, how so? I don't even have users in my database.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :clients, controllers: { registrations: 'clients/registrations', sessions: 'clients/sessions' }
  root to: "mainpages#index"

  get '/mainpages', controller: 'mainpages', action: 'index'
  get '/planes', controller: 'planes', action: 'planes'

  resources :planes
```

My controllers are inside of controllers/clients, At the moment I want to activate all the related with registration and sessions, so here's my registration controller

**registrations_controller**

```
class Clients::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
   before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  # GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
     super
     @client = Client.new
   end

  # POST /resource
   def create
     super
     @client = Client.new(client_params)

     #Set user perms to provider or to client

       if @client.perms == false
         @client.perms = "Client"
       else
         @client.perms = "Provider"
       end

         @client.status = "Not activated"

       if @client.save 
         return redirect_to :root
       end
       render 'new'
   end

   protected

   def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
   end

  # The path used after sign up.
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     super(resource)
   end

  private
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :last_name, :email, :country, :username, :city, :address, :date, :perms, :status)
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Clients::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb** views/mainpages/

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><h4>Not a member?</h4>
    <%= link_to '<p>You can create an account:</p>'.html_safe, controller: "clients/registrations", action:"new" %>
        <p class="text-center">
            <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt big-icon"></i>'.html_safe, controller: "clients/registrations", action:"new" %>
        </p>
</div>
```

I tried to manually sign out by typing localhost:3000/clients/sign_out but I get a routing error, my link to the sign up page doesn't work if I don't get rid of that session, tried to restart the server but I still get the same error.

Comment: Signing out by merely typing localhost:3000/clients/sign_out won't work because it expects the DELETE verb in the http request, not GET. Have you tried to create a sign out link? `<%= link_to, "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>`
Other than that I assume the code in our custom controllers is mixing stuff up.